# React - Pass an array into setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I pass an array into a `setState`? As you can see there is a checkbox that renders and once `onchange` is called the id is put into the state but if there are multiple checkboxes it overwrites each time `onchange` is called.

```
  getInitialState() {
    return {
        listid: []
    }
},    


  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
        listid: e.target.name,
    });
},

 renderCheckbox() {
    const data = this.state.data || [];
    return data.map((list, i) => {
        return (
            <Checkbox
                key={i}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                name={list.id}
                value="Yes"
                label={description}
            />
        );
    });
},
```

Comment: So you want to keep an array of `listid` indicating if the checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: Yes that is precisely what i want it to do

Answer (score 1):

You could check in your `handleChange` function if the checkbox id is present in the `listid` array. If it is, you remove it. If it isn't, you add it.

You can then check if the checkbox id is present in the `listid` array in the render method to decide if it should be checked or not.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkboxes: [{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" }, { id: "4" }],
    listIds: []
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name } = event.target;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const { listIds } = prevState;
      if (listIds.includes(name)) {
        return { listIds: listIds.filter(id => id !== name) };
      } else {
        return { listIds: [...listIds, name] };
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { checkboxes, listIds } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {checkboxes.map(checkbox => (
          <input
            key={checkbox.id}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={listIds.includes(checkbox.id)}
            name={checkbox.id}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I was going to write a very similar code to this, as always you are fast :) But, I am happy that I can reach the very similar conclusions like those situations. I feel that I'm getting better everyday.

Comment: I get Uncaught Error: mergeIntoWithNoDuplicateKeys():Tried to merge two objects with the same key: errors

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an array containing the state of multiple checkboxes, you need to tell `handleChange` *which* checkbox you want to change:

```
<Checkbox
  key={i}
  onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, i)}
  name={list.id}
  value="Yes"
  label={description}
/>
```

You must then create  a temporary copy of the state array, mutate the appropriate item, then replace the old array with the new one:

```
handleChange(e, i) {
  const arr = this.state.listid.slice();
  arr[i] = e.target.name;
  this.setState({listid: arr});
}
```

---

A better approach though would be to pass the index `i` as a prop down to `Checkbox` and then do: `this.props.onClick(this.props.index)` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, classic. Here are the changes you can make to `renderCheckBox`.

```
        <Checkbox
            key={i}
            onChange={(el) => this.handleChange(el, i)}
            name={list.id}
            value="Yes"
            label={description}
        />
```

In your `handleChange`, you can then do

```
handleChange(el, index) {
  let listid = [ ...this.state.listid ];
  listid[index] = el.target.name;
  this.setState({
    listid,
});
```

Comment: Hi there. Mutating the state is not so advisable. Maybe instead of assigning it directly you can use `const listid = [ ...this.state.listid ];`

Comment: I get Uncaught Error: mergeIntoWithNoDuplicateKeys():Tried to merge two objects with the same key: `errors`